# uniform distribution modulo 1 equivalent definition

Tags: real-analysis

I recently came accross the definition of a sequence of real numbers being uniformly distributed modulo $1$. The definition is:

For every choice of $a,b$ with $0 \le a < b < 1$, we have:

$\frac{1}{n}\cdot \#\left\{j \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\} | \{x_j\} \in [a,b]\right\}$ converges to $b - a$  for $n\to \infty$.

{$x_j$} denotes the fractional part of $x_j$ and $\#$ is the number of elements of the set.

Now, it is stated that we can replace $[a,b]$ with $[a, b)$ and get the same answer. I'm a bit stuck on how to actually prove this, am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More precisely, [equidistribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) .

Answer (score 1):

Without loss we can assume that $x_i\in[0,1)$ by replacing them with their mod $1$ residues at the beginning. Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. For each $n$ let the "empirical measure" $\mu_n$ be the average of the point masses at the first $n$ of the $x_i$, defined by:
$$\mu_n(A) = \frac 1 n \operatorname{card}\{i: x_i\in A,  1\le i\le n\},$$
which is to say $$\mu_n = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{x_i},$$
where $\delta_p$ denotes the unit point mass at $p$.

The question is, suppose $\mu_n([a,b))\to\mu([a,b))$ for all $0\le a\le b<1)$. Does this imply $\mu_n([a,b])\to\mu([a,b])$ for all $a\le b\le1$?

Answer: yes.  For if it failed, there would be some $a$ and $b$ for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n([a,b])$ did not exist or did not equal $b-a$. That would imply that $\mu_n(\{b\})$ failed to converge to $0$.  But that cannot be, since for every $\epsilon>0$, $b\in[b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$ and it is known that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(\{b\}) \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n([b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon))=2\epsilon.$$

This state of affairs is usually called [equidistribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) and amounts to the [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) of the measures $\mu_n$ to $\mu$.  The "Portmanteau theorem" gives many equivalent sets of necessary and sufficient conditions for this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_j \sim \mathcal{U}\left([0,1]\right)$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and independent, then $$P( x_j \in [a,b]) = P(x_j \in [a,b)) = b-a$$ where $P(\cdot)$ denotes the probability

Now let $$Y = \#\{ j \in \{1,\ldots, n-1\} | x_j \in A\}$$ be the number of $x_j$ till $n-1$ which are in the set $A$.

Then $Y$ can be written as: 
$$Y = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1_{\{x_j \in A\}}$$

Now you already have for $A = [a,b]$ that $$\frac{1}{n} Y = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1_{\{x_j \in A\}} \to (b-a)$$

and want to know if it also holds for $A = [a,b)$.

But this is pretty obvious by considering that $$1_{\{x_j \in [a,b]\}} = 1_{\{x_j \in [a,b)\}} + 1_{\{x_j = b\}}$$

But $$1_{\{x_j = b\}} = 0$$ $P$-almost surely because the $x_j$ are uniformly distributed.

And so we get: $$\#\{ j \in \{1,\ldots, n-1\} | x_j \in [a,b]\} = \#\{ j \in \{1,\ldots, n-1\} | x_j \in [a,b)\} \quad P-\text{almost surely}$$

Comment: This confuses "uniform distribution" in the sense of probability theory, asking about typical sequences of numbers generated by some random process, and "equidistribution" which talks about the behavior of one particular non random sequence of numbers.  This answer is about the former, but the OP was about the latter.